# The app.server.deploy.dir(C:\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0/../bundles/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps) is not valid

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, plugins, liferay

I downloaded [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/7.0.0%20GA1/liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956.zip/download), and put it on a folder of my choose. Then, when I try to create a new Eclipse Plugin project, everything goes fine until the "Liferay plugins SDK Setting Page" appears. Then, I'm not able to do anything.

I point to the folder of my plugins sdk page, which is:

> C:\Zerok\DevZone\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0

And I get the following error:

> The
>   app.server.deploy.dir(C:\Zerok\DevZone\liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0/../bundles/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps)
>   is not valid.

After this, I can't do anything. Any help with this?

EDIT:

Check this screenshot: I realized that I was pointing to a 7.0 version SDK, while I have the 6.2, but it fails this way too. Check the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have downloaded a Liferay plugins SDK. In order to have a plugin working, you need to deploy the plugin in a Liferay Server (tipically a Liferay bundle with a tomcat).

The deploy dir is the directory where Liferay will search for new plugins and deploy them.

If have not missed anything from your question, you need a server.

EDIT: 
Indeed, I missed something. You have a server (6.2).

First, you need a proper Plugins SDK for Liferay 6.2.
Second, in the build.properties inside that SDK is defined the default properties for building the projects. You can override them with a build.[your-user].properties and set the correct deploy dir there.

Regards

Comment: Gotta check it tomorrow at the office, thank you! Will accept the answer if it works

Comment: Still not working. It keeps throwing the same error. I moved the 6.2 plugin SDK into the deploy folder of my working Liferay 6.2 server, but it keeps throwing the same error...

Comment: Moved the plugins SDK to the deploy folder?

No. You should check the properties set in the build.properties inside your plugins SDK and override what you need to match your server path.

Create a "build.${user.name}.properties" and set something like:

`
    app.server.parent.dir=/path/to/my/liferay-portal-6.2
    app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-7.0.62
`

Be sure the app.server.tomcat.dir points to your existing server.

Comment: I created a build called "build.zerok.properties", and set this as its content: app.server.parent.dir=C:\Zerok\DevZone\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5
app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-7.0.62
... Still not working tho. Gives the same error...

Comment: If you are still getting the same path error, then your build.properties are not being overriden.<br/>
Is zerok your Windows logged in user? Check with `echo %username%` <br/>
Maybe you can try to override the build.properties (bad practise!) just to check if it goes to the right server path, and after that fight with the overriding problem.

Comment: I changed the app.server.parent.dir to =${sdk.dir}, which points to C:/Zerok/DevZone/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5 (which is an actual directory!), and it still fails... I'm beginning to think this is really badly built, I never had a problem like this with any development tool/framework.

Comment: By the way, the error is "he app.server.deploy.dir(C:\Zerok\DevZone\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5\deploy\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps) is not valid.". If I copy the directory and paste it on explorer, it forwards me to that directory, so it is actually valid! But, still, I can't do anything and I'm going to have serious problems if I don't fix this...

Comment: First, Liferay is not either a development tool or a framework. It is an open source portal platform that allows you to deploy or develop your own plugins (JSR-186, JSR-268). And it's really easy to configure to start developing for it (please have a look at https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/beginning-liferay-development).

Comment: Talking about your properties, please don't mix sdk with server. You just need a server and an sdk. And each must have their properties correctly set. Don't point your server to sdk.dir. Keep them separated. Btw, if a right path is not resolved, maybe it's just because of the unescaped path separator. Consider using "\\" or "/". But, first, keep your sdk and server separated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111197/discussion-between-zerok-and-juan-manuel-rogado).

Answer (score 3):

In order for this work correctly in your liferay-plugins-sdk-7.0 folder, you must create a build.${user.name}.properties and in this file you must set "app.server.parent.dir" and point it to the directory that contains the extracted liferay portal 7.0 ga1 files.

```
app.server.parent.dir=C:/Zerok/DevZone/liferay/liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1
```

Or where ever you have installed unzipped the portal zip.  Then try again in the wizard in Liferay IDE.

Note: its better to use forward slashes in your config, '/' instead of backslashes.  If you do use backslashes you must use two of them '\\'

Answer (score 0):

gamerson has answered it correctly but I want add some more stuff to this answer.

You need to add a properties file--> build.{username}.properties in your plugin sdk folder.

And also need to add various properties.

app.server.portal.dir = **E:\test\liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1**\tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\ROOT

app.server.lib.global.dir = **E:\test\liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1**\tomcat-8.0.32\lib\ext

app.server.parent.dir = **E:\test\liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1**

app.server.tomcat.dir = **E:\test\liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1**\tomcat-8.0.32

app.server.tomcat.deploy.dir = **E:\test\liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1**\tomcat-8.0.32\webapps

app.server.type = tomcat

app.server.dir = **E:\test\liferay-portal-7.0-ce-ga1**\tomcat-8.0.32

copy your tomcat directory and place where bold text is.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to gamerson, just create a properties file build.{UserName}.properties file under plugins sdk directory and add only one property 
`app.server.parent.dir=D:/LifeRay/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3`

please note {UserName} is windows/linux username and while specifying property value, use `\\` in windows env or / in linux env pointing to liferay home.

please close all dialogs in eclipse and recreate the plugin project again